# Detecting Scroll with InputListener

Tags: java, zooming, libgdx

Oh well... i'm having a problem that i don't know what's wrong.

I have a stage with a few Tiles (square actors of 128x128 size) inside a table.

what i want to do is, when i scroll up, the camera zooms out, when i scroll down, the camera zooms in.
I read libgdx documentation and figured out a way to try to make that work but... something is missing and i don't know what it is, somewhat it looks like the InputListener isn't getting my scrolling action.

To test it, I tried just printing some information about the scrolling action to the console, but that didn't work.

Here is my InputListener:

```
private class MouseEvents extends InputListener{

    public void enter(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor) {
        setDrawable(new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(selected)));
    }

    public void exit(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor) {
        setDrawable(new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(unselected)));
    }

    public boolean scrolled(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int amount){
        System.out.println("ZoomValue: " + amount + " at " + x + "x" + y);
        return true;
    }

}
```

The enter and exit methods work perfectly, but the scrolled one doesn't, if i add this listener to a Tile or a listener just with the scrolled() method to the stage or even the table with the tiles, nothing happens.

My idea was to add it to the stage to zoom in and out the viewport, but... well, any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You must use an [InputProcessor](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html):

```
public class MyInputProcessor implements InputProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled (int amount){
        //Use the ammount wisely!
        return false;
    }

    @Override public boolean keyDown (int keycode) { return false; }
    @Override public boolean keyUp (int keycode) { return false; }
    @Override public boolean keyTyped (char character) { return false; }
    @Override public boolean touchDown (int x, int y, int pointer, int button) { return false; }
    @Override public boolean touchUp (int x, int y, int pointer, int button) { return false; }
    @Override public boolean touchDragged (int x, int y, int pointer) { return false; }
    @Override public boolean touchMoved (int x, int y) { return false; }
}
```

Dont forget to set it:

```
MyInputProcessor inputProcessor = new MyInputProcessor();
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputProcessor);
```

Reference: [Event Handling](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling)

Answer (score -1):

Consider using the mouseWheelMoved method. It is built right into java and should get you what you're looking for. Consider going to [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/awt/event/mouse-wheel-event-example/) for a more in-depth tutorial than what I can give.

Comment: `mouseWheelMoved` is a method on AWT controls, the question was about [libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/).